# Area 51 'Top Beta Users' should be pruned occasionally

Tags: feature-request, area-51, top-users

A long time ago, in a galaxy far far away, [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com) was proposed by our very own [Adam Davis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2915/adam-davis) as '[Not Programming Related](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related)'. The site has undergone rather radical topic changes since its beta period, which resulted in several prolific users leaving the site.

Currently, these users are displayed as broken image links on the top beta users page on Area 51 as flare no longer exists for them on the parent site.

Can we anonymize them, or perhaps not display beta users that no longer have an account on the site at all? On the one hand, they're broken images - they should be fixed. On the other, it feels kind of icky to display those users like that.

Comment: The [fix implemented](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3352/not-programming-related) seems reasonable. This question came up in the Review Queue, closing because it's status-completed.